# how to call a different class from within an if/else statement?

Tags: java, class, if-statement

I am creating a banking application for my assignment, I would like to know if it's possible to call another class from an if/else statement? if so, where have I gone wrong? as when before compiling I get no errors, but many errors when trying to run. I would like to call the 'public void currentAccountCreate in the currentAccount.java class. I also have a main menu page.
many thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    currentAccount currentAccountCreating = new currentAccount();
    //savingsAccount savingsAccountCreating = new savingsAccount();

    public void accountCreation(){
        String createOption = "";
        boolean valid = false;
        while (!valid) {
            System.out.println("What account would you like to create?");
            System.out.println("Current or savings?");
            createOption = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (createOption.equalsIgnoreCase("current")) {
                currentAccountCreating.currentAccountCreate();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid account type selected. Please enter checking or savings");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to call

```
public class currentAccount extends Account {
    public void currentAccountCreate() {
```

Error stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source) at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at assignmentmine.Account.<init>(Account.java:7)
    at assignmentmine.currentAccount.<init>(currentAccount.java:5)
    // Plus a load more related ones
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Unknown Source)   at sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)   at assignmentmine.Account.<init>(Account.java:7)
 at assignmentmine.currentAccount.<init>(currentAccount.java:5)  Plus a load more related ones

Comment: You'll have to edit the question to include the contents of currentAccount. It looks like you are passing something invalid into some currency method

Comment: Your problem is neither `currentAccountCreate` or `accountCreation`. Rethink what fields you have in the `Account` class and how you initialize them.

Comment: There is nothing in current account for me to call, i just added a simple Sout line to see if it correctly called it

Comment: What do you think will happen when you create a new `currentAccount` instance? It obviously also creates a new `Account` instance which has to call `new currentAccount()` to initialize `currentAccountCreating` and this also has to call `Account`, which also calls `new currentAccount()` to init its own `currentAccountCreating` and I guess you know what will happen next. So again: rethink what you're doing there.

Comment: When will valid become true? Here it is always false and while loop is repeated forever and throwing stackoverflow error. There should be some way to set valid as true.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "call" a class, but you can initialize an object of a class and use its public functions. **Also,** it would be helpful if you said what class you wish to call.

For example, if I have two classes `Checking` and `Savings` I would initialize them inside an if/else statement like this:

```
//pseudocode
if (something)
   Checking obj;
else
   Savings obj;
```

**However,** if your question was about creating another instance of the current class, then all you need to do is initialize an object of the current class inside the class itself. Here is an example:

```
public class Checking {
   Checking obj;
}
```

**Note:**

- The while-loop has no way to stop, it keeps repeating forever!

Comment: if the user typed in 'current' I would like the IDE to open the code from my class 'currentAccount' as opposed to me writing the code in the same class as the choice of account type

Comment: You do not need to rewrite or to "call" the class. If the user decided to choose `Current` account, then you would need to create an object of that class inside the if/else statement and then use that  object to use the functions that are within the `Current` class.